# Implicit and explicit exception difference

Tags: java

What's the difference between implicit exception and explicit exception?

If I declare catch block like: catch(Exception e). Is this implicitly declaring an exception, or explicitly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never heard of "implicit" and "explicit" exception.

Comment: I think he means something like this: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0317/#implicit-instantiation
(python)

Comment: Just wanted to add this info here. There may not be an implicit or explicit exception but we generally use the term implicitly thrown exceptions or explicitly thrown exceptions.<br/> e.g. run() of Runnable interface implicitly throws RuntimeException as any checked exception is not defined in run() method. Whereas, call() in Callable explicitly throw Exception type exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's any such term as "implicit exception" or "explicit exception". Are you thinking checked and unchecked exceptions perhaps?

I've just downloaded the language specification as a PDF, and the phrases "implicit exception" and "explicit exception" don't exist anywhere within it.

Could you say where you came across the terms?

Comment: Hello Jon. There is a line in page no. 470 in Head First servlets, and the line is: "Declaring an error page for a more explicit exception." Could you please tell me what they mean with "explicit exception" here?

Comment: Ah - I suspect that means "declaring an error page for a specific type of exception." In other words, you might have one error page for "anything has gone wrong" and a different one for "AuthenticationException".

Comment: More explicit in this context means for an exception type that is of a derived type (being more specific) than the more general base class type.

Comment: Comment posted as an edit suggestion: "Hi! In the Deitel: Java How to Program 8e book at page 455. it writes that "A compilation error occurs if a method explicitly attempts to throw a checked exception (or calls another method that throws a checked exception) and that exception is not listed in that method's throws clause"

Comment: @jjnguy: Not sure what edit you're suggesting... but there's obviously a big difference between the phrase "implicit exception" and "explicitly attempts to throw a checked exception".

Comment: @Jon, sorry to be unclear.  The comment I posted was originally appended to the end of your answer as an edit suggestion.  I just thought you might like to know, so I copied it out of the suggestion, and pasted it as a comment as it should have been.

Answer (score 1):

I think implicitly instantiating an object is done without explicitly calling a constructor. I don't think you can do that in Java.

Example:

```
throw new Exception();
```

calls a constructor and then throws the newly created `Exception` object.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. Catching is not declaring an exception. Declaring an exception happens on the method:

```
public void someMethod() throws Exception.
```

I'm not sure what you mean by implicit vs. explicit. You probably mean something like the difference between a runtime and checked exception, but you could also a mean a method which throws a Runtime exception, which is optional.

```
public void someMethod() throws NullPointerException
```

The throws in that case is purely optional, since it is a Runtime exception, nothing should happen differently.

Answer (score 0):

This only applies to the first part of your question:

The terms explicit and implicit exceptions do exist and relate to how a Java virtual machine handles exceptions. From the end-user (Java programmer) view, they are the same (besides the obvious performance benefit).

Explicit exceptions are ones explicitly checked for by the JVM. For example every array indexing operation you do, is explicitly checked for being in range by the JVM.

Implicit exceptions are ones that are thrown in the aftermath. For example `NullPointerException` and `StackOverflowException` are thrown in the handler routine for the segmentation fault. This is quite a performance boost as the JVM gets signaled by the OS instead of having to incur an overhead on every operation that might throw.